# Azure LogicApp custom connector publishing

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-platform

How can I check my LogicApp custom connector before publishing?

I am seeing support only for Power Platform (Power Apps) but I want to check it in LogicApp env.

Using [paconn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/paconn-cli#installing) utility.

Also LogicApp custom connector only have one (json) file available for downloading,

And it doesn't seem in the format of [PowerPlatformConnectors](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatformConnectors).

Full guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/certification-submission#step-3d-validate-your-custom-connector-files

Comment: Which step are you up to?

Comment: @Castrohenge This is not relevant for me anymore :) and this is an issue for MS actually